# Unsure of Control flow in Pandas

Tags: pandas, if-statement

I've been working on a Pandas project in Python and am confused a bit on how to accomplish a condition in Pandas.

The code at the below shows how i sort of propose to calculate business_minutes and calendar_minutes between a close_date and a open_date. It works great except when close_date has not yet been recorded or that it is null.

I'm thinking I can use control logic something like the following except I know the logic is not sound.  Is there a way to do what i'd like to do but correctly?

```py
if close_date:
    df_incident['Bus_Mins'] = df_incident.apply(lambda x: bduration(x['Open_Date'], x['Close_Date']), axis=1)
    df_incident['Cal_Mins'] = (df_incident['Close_Date'] - df_incident['Open_Date']).dt.total_seconds()/60
elif:
    now = dt.now(timezone.utc)
    df_incident['Bus_Mins'] = df_incident.apply(lambda x: bduration(x['Open_Date'], now), axis=1)
    df_incident['Cal_Mins'] = (now - df_incident['Open_Date']).dt.total_seconds()/60



    # get current utc time
    now = dt.now(timezone.utc)

    # set start and stop times of business day
    #Specify Business Working hours (7am - 5pm)
    start_time = dt.time(7,00,0)
    end_time = dt.time(17,0,0)

    us_holidays = pyholidays.US() 
    unit='min'

    # Create a partial function as a shortcut
    bduration = partial(bd.businessDuration, starttime=start_time, endtime=end_time, holidaylist=us_holidays, unit=unit)

    df_incident['Bus_Mins'] = df_incident.apply(lambda x: bduration(x['Open_Date'], x['Close_Date']), axis=1)
    df_incident['Cal_Mins'] = (df_incident['Close_Date'] - df_incident['Open_Date']).dt.total_seconds()/60
```

Have I presented my need clearly?  Is it possible to do?

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: You can put three backticks (`\`\`\``) by itself on the lines above and below your code to format it as code. Write the word "python" (without quotes) next to the backticks starting the code block to add syntax highlighting to the Python code.

Comment: @JeffVanderDoes posting some data would help us understand what you are wanting to do.  `df_incident.head().to_dict()` for example

Answer (score 0):

As written, your code will not work because you call `bduration()` before defining it. Also, you assign to Bus_Mins and Cal_Mins twice in the body of the else condition. The second assignment will probably not work because close date is null. It is a syntax error to have an elif without a condition, so `else:` should be used instead. Something like the following might work:

```py
# set start and stop times of business day
#Specify Business Working hours (7am - 5pm)
start_time = dt.time(7,00,0)
end_time = dt.time(17,0,0)

us_holidays = pyholidays.US() 
unit='min'

# Create a partial function as a shortcut
bduration = partial(bd.businessDuration, starttime=start_time, endtime=end_time, holidaylist=us_holidays, unit=unit)

if close_date:
    df_incident['Bus_Mins'] = df_incident.apply(lambda x: bduration(x['Open_Date'], x['Close_Date']), axis=1)
    df_incident['Cal_Mins'] = (df_incident['Close_Date'] - df_incident['Open_Date']).dt.total_seconds()/60
else:
    # get current utc time
    now = dt.now(timezone.utc)
    df_incident['Bus_Mins'] = df_incident.apply(lambda x: bduration(x['Open_Date'], now), axis=1)
    df_incident['Cal_Mins'] = (now - df_incident['Open_Date']).dt.total_seconds()/60
```